# NSPredicate issue for getting an image url with its size in URL

Tags: objective-c, parsing, core-data, nspredicate

Here's my problem.

I'm using an HTML parser for parsing an HTML content.

When i'm matching an image usig this pattern

```
http://www.site.com/path/to/image/image-name-heightxwidth.extension
```

I'm want get on my core data database the matching url for this image using this pattern :

```
http://www.site.com/path/to/image/image-name.extension
```

What is the correct "predicate with format" i should use for preforming my request ?

**EDIT :** Here's the code for where i perform my request on the data base

```
- (WPImage *)imageMatchingUrl:(NSString *)urlString {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url CONTAINS %@",urlString];
    ALog(@"WPImage for urlString %@ found ? : %@",urlString, [self getEntities:NSStringFromClass([WPImage class]) withPredicate:predicate][0]?@"Yes":@"No");
    return [self getEntities:NSStringFromClass([WPImage class]) withPredicate:predicate][0];

}
```

Comment: I think the predicate won't work you should have a look on NNSRegularExpression instead.

Comment: Yep ! I think it's the best solution !
But what Regular expression should i use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try regular expression NSPattern cannot do this, this should do the job:

```
    NSString *st1 = @"http://www.site.com/path/to/image/image-name-300x200.extension";

    NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [st1 length]);
    NSString *pattern = @"-\\d+x\\d+";
    NSError  *error = nil;

    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:st1 options:0 range: searchedRange];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches)
    {
        NSString* matchText = [st1 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:[match range] withString:@""];

        NSLog(@"Match: %@", matchText);
    }
```

Comment: I should use this predicate : 
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url CONTAINS %@",result]; 
or this one :
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url == %@",result];

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you want to achieve. I thought that you want to remove from url string text: '-heightxwidth' , for example '-300x300'. And my regex will work for that. If there is not true can you please explain what is your pattern? I cannot see a lot from your predicate example.

Comment: Yes sure ! But then ! My function should return an "WPImage" where the property "url" match the result from your regex in my Database :)

Comment: If there is no object in marches array it means that the pattern was not found. But if there is one in for loop matchText variable keep your url string so base on that string you can create predicate [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url = %@", matchText];. You have to use NSRegularExpression because your image name can be different, I guess, for example 20x20, 300x300, etc and you NSPredictate won't work in this scenario.